Relationship of projection of same point onto different sets
Suppose we have two closed, convex and bounded sets $A$ and $B$, with $A\subset B$, and assume both sets contain the origin. let $x$ be an arbitrary point and let $p(x,A)$ and $p(x,B)$ be the metric projection of $x$ onto $A$ and $B$ respectively. I want to say something about the distance of each of the projections from zero.
In the simple case where the two sets are of the 'same shape', then intuitively $\|p(x,A)-0\|_2=\|p(x,A)\|_2 \le \|p(x,B)\|_2$. Think of a circle in another larger circle, the projections will lie on the same line, and the smaller set projection will obviously be closer to the origin.
I am more interested in cases where the sets are of different shape. I'm not sure what the right notion here is. For example, suppose $x$ is closest to $A$ at an edge that is a line segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(0,0)$, and that it is closed to $B$ at edge that lies on the line $y=cx$  for $c<1$. Then it is clear that the project onto $A$ might have larger norm than the projection onto $B$.
I'm mainly looking for advice on how to approach this problem in a more systematic way, using the properties of projections and a notion of how the two sets relate to eaech other. At the moment I have just been able to do simple geometric examples manually.

I imagine you need some more structure before saying much.
First, metric projections can happen in arbitrary metric spaces but you are using a norm. Not all metric spaces allow a norm so perhaps you are concerned with projections in normed linear spaces(called Banach if also complete). The more structure on your space, the more you'll be able to say.
$inf_{y \in S} d(x,S)$ exists for any $S \subseteq X$ but the infimum may not be attained. That is there are no closest points. Even when the infimum is attained there may be more than one point closest to $x$. So the projection $P(x,S)$ is a set-valued function whose value may be $\emptyset$.
Working with strictly convex spaces(e.g. a Hilbert space) guarantees $|p(x,S)| \leq 1$, meaning the projection is unique when it exists. then you only need to worry about the existence which the closedness and convexity of the set take care of.
I'm guessing you should work with Hilbert spaces so you can focus on your actual question rather than these technicalities.
As you've pointed out, even with the structure of Hilbert spaces the norm of the projection onto the smaller set may be bigger. One idea might be looking at how much smaller $A$ is, its measure compared to $B$, or the length of the longest line segment connecting a point on the boundary of $A$ to a point on the boundary of $B$, etc.
Another idea could be to focus more on the shapes the sets have. We know that projecting into a set containing $0$ decreases the norm so you'd have what you want if projection into $A$ is equivalent to projecting into $B$ and then into $A$.

thanks for the suggestions - i  agree that assumptions need to be placed to make sure the projection exists and is unique. My question is more about what geometric characteristics of the sets determines the behavior of the projection though..
